# Exequte put method with body and bearer token

Tags: c#, angular, api

The following code excecutes a put method in my webapi from `Angular 7`:

```
public getData(objTimes: Times) {
let bearer = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', bearer);
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.put('https://localhost:44388/api/times', objTimes, 
 options);
}
```

Without security the method return items, but when I place the following line in the class in my WebApi:

```
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

The error generated from my angular code is 400 (BAD REQUEST)

The token is generated for 10 minutes if after 10 minutes I try to call the method the error return is 401 (Unauthorized).

Comment: Show your request headers and body from developer console/network section please (f12). It will be clear then

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

return this.http.put(
    'https://localhost:44388/api/times', 
    { 
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("TOKEN"),
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      )
    }
);
```